# Safety of SSL / HTTPS when sending known message across websockets, e.g. Open Source?

Tags: javascript, ssl, websocket

My concern is that, if I distribute some open source code which uses websockets to communicate, will it be unsafe if the messages are known beforehand?

For example, if the message is a simple thing like:

```
"chat:username7->username5:hi, username5"
```

Or even a message which is 100% known, such as:

```
"chatdisconnect"
```

Does this weaken the security provided by SSL by a significant amount?  If so, what would be a good direction to go in order to provide messages like these in a secure way from Javascript to the server?  Would further encryption be necessary, even though Javascript running in the browser is already public to the user?

Comment: SSL/TLS is randomized during the handshake. So it doesn't matter if the message is known, it is still secure during transit. Make multiple connections and send the same message, they will be encrypted to different bytes.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that.  That's good to hear.